# How to equalize the value of the integer in the 64 Bit to 32 Bit

Tags: php, integer, 64-bit, 32-bit

I want to match the value of the integer in 64bit and 32bit systems, this is an example of my PHP script

```
function integer_hash_aritmathic ($value)
{       
    $maxVal = 2147483647 & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    $minVal = -2147483648 & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    $hash = 0;  

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++)
    {
        $hash = (intval($hash) * 31) + ord($value[$i]);

        if ($hash > $maxVal) $hash = $hash + $minVal - $maxVal - 1;
        else if ($hash < $minVal) $hash = $hash + $maxVal - $minVal + 1;

    }


    return (int)$hash;
}

echo integer_hash_aritmathic ('21512510');
```

output in 32Bit System : 
-951649475

Output in 64Bit System : 
1283243572029

I want the same results on a 64bit system with 32bit, with the value of -951649475, please help me... thanks, I'am sory my english language is bad...

Comment: What is the value of $minVal on the 64-bit system?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to emulate 32 bit overflow on the 64 bit system.

The problem is probably that on a 64-bit system `$minVal = -2147483648 & 0xFFFFFFFF` zeroes the sign bits, setting the value of $minval to 2147483648.
`$hash = $hash + $minVal - $maxVal - 1` then effectively becomes `$hash = $hash` and all calculations are done using the full integer size.

If you remove the `& 0xFFFFFFFF` which is causing the problem on 64-bit systems (and have no effect on 32-bit systems) your code should work.

Another option is to limit the hash values to 31 bits, resulting in only positive numbers.

The code can then be simplified to

```
function integer_hash_aritmathic ($value){       
    $hash = 0;  

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++) {
        $hash = ($hash * 31 + ord($value[$i])) & 0x7FFFFFFF;               
    }

    return (int)$hash;
}
```